# ghdl never terminates and I don't know, why

Tags: vhdl, ghdl

2022 is supposed to be the year where I plan to dig deeper into fpga programming. I really did not do anything of that kind in over 25 years (back then, I did some GAL logic).
So for all intents and purposes, you can consider this the post of a newbie as far as HDL stuff goes.

And what I try to do is trivial, really - a simple adder with carry and borrow and a respective test bench.

```
-- add1.vhdl
library IEEE;
use IEEE.std_logic_1164.all;

entity add1 is
port ( 
  borrow : in std_ulogic;
  a : in std_ulogic;
  b : in std_ulogic;
  o : out std_ulogic;
  carry : out std_ulogic;
  err : out std_ulogic);
end add1;

architecture add1arch of add1 is
begin
  process
    variable inputs : std_ulogic_vector(2 downto 0);
  begin
    inputs := borrow & a & b;
    err <= '0';
    case inputs is
      when "000" => 
        o <= '0';
        carry <= '0';
      when "100" =>
        o <= '1';
        carry <= '0';
      when "010" =>
        o <= '1';
        carry <= '0';
      when "001" =>
        o <= '1';
        carry <= '0';
      when "011" =>
        o <= '0';
        carry <= '1';
      when "110" =>
        o <= '0';
        carry <= '0';
      when "101" =>
        o <= '0';
        carry <= '0';
      when "111" =>
        o <= '1';
        carry <= '1';
      when others =>
        o <= '0';
        carry <= '0';
        err <= '1';
    end case;
  end process;
end architecture;
```

And the test bench looks like this:

```
-- add1_tb.vhdl
library IEEE;
use IEEE.std_logic_1164.all;

entity add1_tb is
end add1_tb;    

architecture test of add1_tb is
  component add1
    port ( 
      borrow : in std_ulogic;
      a : in std_ulogic;
      b : in std_ulogic;
      o : out std_ulogic;
      carry : out std_ulogic;
      err : out std_ulogic);
  end component;

  signal borrow, a, b, o, carry, err : std_ulogic;
  signal inputs : std_ulogic_vector(2 downto 0);
begin
  adder: add1 port map
    (borrow => borrow,
     a => a,
     b => b,
     o => o,
     carry => carry,
     err => err);
  process
  begin
    inputs <= borrow & a & b;

    inputs <= "XXX";
    wait for 1 ns;
    
    inputs <= "000";
    wait for 1 ns;

    inputs <= "001";
    wait for 1 ns;

    inputs <= "010";
    wait for 1 ns;

    inputs <= "011";
    wait for 1 ns;
    
    inputs <= "100";
    wait for 1 ns;

    inputs <= "101";
    wait for 1 ns;

    inputs <= "110";
    wait for 1 ns;

    inputs <= "111";
    wait for 1 ns;

    assert false report "done.";
    wait;
    
  end process;
end architecture;
```

Using

> ghdl --version
> GHDL 1.0.0 (Debian 1.0.0+dfsg-3) [Dunoon edition]
> Compiled with GNAT Version: 10.2.1 20210110
> mcode code generator
> Written by Tristan Gingold.
> Copyright (C) 2003 - 2021 Tristan Gingold.
> GHDL is free software, covered by the GNU General Public License.  There is NO
> warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

On a Debian bullseye 64 bit machine.
Building with:

> ghdl --clean
> ghdl -a add1.vhdl
> ghdl -a add1_tb.vhdl
> ghdl -e add1_tb
> ghdl -r add1_tb --vcd=add1.vcd

The last command never terminates and when I control-c it after a while, the `add1.vcd` file is empty.

Now here the question, which will help me determine if I have tool chain problems or bugs in my vhdl code:

Does anyone see anything wrong with my code? (I know its clumsy but since I get no errors or warnings, I assume it is syntactically correct.)

Comment: add1 is syntactically and semantically correct. `ghdl -a add1.vhdl` gives `add1.vhdl:17:3:warning: infinite loop for this process without a wait statement [-Wno-wait]`. It's not illegal, just won't work, the process never suspends. Suspension and subsequent resumption of a process occurs in a wait statement. The easiest fix is to add a sensitivity list with every signal evaluated in an expression. A more current release will have better error and warning messages.

Comment: I added the `process` here, so I have a place, where I can declare my `variable inputs..`.  Trying to write the logic right into the architecture block failed because of that.

Comment: Your last comment is without foundation in my comment or your question.

Comment: As I said - vhdl newbie here. I wanted that inputs vector and did not think I need a process for asynchronous logic - but this was the first solution for my declaration problem.

Comment: And now you have two comments that can't be readily resolved. Note your testbench doesn't assign the value of inputs to borrow, a and b or otherwise assign those three inputs to adder. Whole lot of 'X's. Consider the possibility *Does anyone see anything wrong with my code?* is too broad a question and potentially not of interest to future readers.

Comment: @user16145658 I think, my code shows what I am trying to do. If I did mistakes, it is due to it being my very first bit of vhdl code and I wanted to use it to see if the ghdl gtkwave tool chain works. If I have quirks in my vhdl code, I cannot confirm or disconfirm toolchain problems. So, feel free to show how to do the same in a more idiomatic way in your answer.

Comment: I haven't answered. See [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer), the bit about *Answer [well-asked](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) questions*. Also see [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [ask]. The idea here is that questions with upvoted answers are a search resource for future readers.

Answer (score 0):

As it turns out, the suggestion about "sensitivity lists" (I had to look up first, what that means...) grants an easy fix to my problem

Obviously, the way, processes are "simulated" when the design is being run, depends on some "triggers" to make the "state machine" proceed. This can be waits or - as I learned now - changes to signals contained in the "sensitivity list" (which is a kind of argument list for a process in programming terms).

So, In order to fix my little problem, all I had to do was...

```
-- add1.vhdl
-- ...
architecture add1arch of add1 is
begin
  process (borrow, a, b) -- list signals in sensitivity list to avoid hangs!
```

As for the other problem in the test bench, my attempt to find nicer notation for my input signals (`"001" instead of "borrow <= 0; a <= 0; b <= 1;"`), I had to make the following changes:

```
-- add1_tb.vhdl
-- ...
  signal inputs : std_ulogic_vector(2 downto 0);
  signal o, carry, err : std_ulogic;
  alias borrow : std_ulogic is inputs(0);
  alias a : std_ulogic is inputs(1);
  alias b : std_ulogic is inputs(2);
-- ...
```

Now it behaves as expected and I can see the gtkwave output.
The only drawback is, that gtkwave does not offer to display the alias values, so I am stuck with the inputs vector for now, instead.

Comment: A concurrent signal assignment statement with an aggregate target: `(borrow, a, b) <= inputs;`